Is there an exact solution to this special integral?
While solving Einstein's field equation for the spacetime of a static fluid sphere, I came across this linear second order homogeneous differential equation:$$f~y''+\frac{1}{2}f'~y'=\frac{1}{4}\Big(\frac{1-f}{x}\Big)' y~ \tag{1}$$ with $$f(x)\equiv 1-x~e^{-2bx}(c+2b~e^{-1}\operatorname{ei}(1+2bx)) \tag{2}$$ where $b$ and $c$ are constant parameters and $$\operatorname{ei}(x)\equiv\int_{-\infty}^x~\frac{e^t}{t}~dt. \tag{3}$$
The particular solutions I found are $$y_{1}=e^{bx},~~~~~y_2=e^{bx}\int\frac{e^{-2bx}}{\sqrt{f(x)}}. \tag{4}$$
Now I'm trying to find out if there's an explicit solution to this integral $$\frac{1}{2b}\int \frac{e^{-u}~d{u}}{\sqrt{1-u \cdot e^{-u} (\frac{c}{2b}+e^{-1}~\operatorname{ei}~(1+u))}},~~~(u\equiv 2bx) .\tag{5}$$ The Wolfram free integrator online can't find one. Any help or advice would be great.

Dear editor, I have provided the required context. Why is this insufficient?

I get it now, thank you for helping.
